# Finding the existence of limit of a given function.

Tags: real-analysis, limits, convergence-divergence

[image]

I tried the L'Hospital Rule

Can any other decent method to solve this sum.

Comment: Forget the Hospital; use the power series expansion of the exponential function.

Answer (score 2):

As Lord Shark has said, it is best that you actually expand $e^{\frac 1{x^3}}$ via  its Taylor expansion.

Note that $e^{\frac 1{x^3}} = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{x^{3n}n!} = 1 + \frac 1{x^3} + \frac 1{2x^6} + O(x^{-9})$. Combining this with the rest of the expression tells you that:
$$
x^n\left(e^{\frac 1{x^3}} - 1 + \frac 1{x^3}\right) = 2x^{n-3} + \frac 12x^{n-6} + O(x^{n-9})
$$

If $n < 3$, then the limit most definitely exists, since the expression above is at least $O(x^{-1})$.

Even when $n=3$, the limit will be $2$, since the rest is $O(x^{-3})$.

However, when $n>3$, the first term will certainly go to $\infty$, and the rest are just positive terms, so the limit will not exist.

It follows that all the above options are true. (In competitive exams, I think this approach works better than L'Hopital, in case this is a competitive exam).

Comment: +1 for the advice in last line. Nothing beats Taylor in terms of speed.

Comment: True. Speaking of which, I think GATE is happening today, so I am sure we will have a few nice questions from that exam coming up in a few days.

Comment: Thought so.  I think that font really seems to be a classical one : I've seen it on all the (Indian) competitive exam questions posted here.

Comment: The font used is very common and goes by name "Times New Roman". Personally I don't like it. The default font (Computer Modern) used by $\mathrm\LaTeX $ like $\text{abcd}$ is much better.

Answer (score 1):

It is from IIT-JAM (entrance exam in india for masters)

we have to find limit of $f(x)$ at $\infty$

**Part (a)**

as we can see $f(x)$ is of form of $\infty \times 0$
we have to write it in the form of $0 \over 0$ to use L'Hopitals Rule 
so we can write the function as

$$f(x)= {e^{1\over x^3}- 1+ {1\over x^3}\over {1\over x}}$$

Now using L'Hopitals Rule i.e we are going to differentiate both numerator and denominator with respect to $x$, we get

$${-3\over x^4} \bigg( {e^{1\over x^3}} +1 \bigg) \over {-1\over x^2} $$

by further simplifying it  we get

$${3\over x^2} \bigg( {e^{1\over x^3}} +1 \bigg)  $$
so now we have

$$\lim_{x\to \infty}f(x)= \lim_{x\to \infty} {3\over x^2} \bigg( {e^{1\over x^3}} +1 \bigg)=0 $$

**Part (b)**

$$xf(x)=  {e^{1\over x^3}- 1+ {1\over x^3}\over {1\over x^2}} $$
 so again we have $0\over 0 $ form, so differentiating Numerator and denominator with respect to x we get

$$=\lim_{x\to \infty}{6\over x} \bigg( {e^{1\over x^3}} +1 \bigg)=0$$

**Part (c)**

$$\lim_{x\to \infty}x^2f(x)= \lim_{x\to \infty} f(x)= {e^{1\over x^3}- 1+ {1\over x^3}\over {1\over x^3}}$$

so again we have $0\over 0 $ form, so differentiating Numerator and denominator with respect to x we get

$$\lim_{x\to \infty}  ({e^{1\over x^3}} +1) =2 $$

**Part (d)**

but for $x$ to the power m where $m>2$ ,limit doesnot exist because then x will dominate lets take $x=m>2$ for example

$$\lim_{x\to \infty}x^mf(x)= \lim_{x\to \infty} x^{m-2}{3\over m+1} \bigg( {e^{1\over x^3}} +1 \bigg)=\infty (for \quad m>2) $$
so our all four options $(a),(b),(c)$ and $(d)$ are correct

*we can do the Part (d)  first interpret others easily because we see in the last part for m-2>0 limit doesnot exist i.e for m>2 limit doesnot exist*

Comment: Your first usage of L'Hospital's Rule is correct, but the later ones are wrong. You can't apply L'Hospital's Rule on a factor of the expression when the expression looks like $\infty \times 0$.

Comment: In fact you can note that $x^2f(x)\to 2$ but you get the limit as $6$

Comment: thanks @ParamanandSingh , How is it now

Comment: Now its OK. I had already given my up vote (perhaps without looking deep) and later realized your mistake. So now the upvote is backed by a correct answer.